# Oauth Twitter and Facebook Apps within iframes

Tags: iframe, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I am writing a browser app to update status' / tweet to Facebook and Twitter automatically on users behalf.

My issue is I need this app to work within an iframe as the app is written in PHP but needs to work within an ASP site.

Is this going to be possible? I have tested this and it seems to update the status when already authenticated but I am having issues authenticating from within the iframe.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter won't allow you to embed its OAuth authentication parts. However, actual requests or anything else isn't a problem.

I'd assume that this is the same for Facebook, especially when you're using PHP to make the requests.

To answer your (second) question: you can probably just get all query data in ASP and pass it to the PHP frame. I've never done ASP but in PHP that would be something as simple as `<iframe src='frame.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>'>`

Comment: yeah I have tested this out and it seems to work when already authenticated, it updates the status no problem.  The problem is the getting it to authenticate.  So I assume there is no way round this then...

Comment: In that case, please click the "This answered my question" icon next to the answer. Thanks :-)