# Twitter login on third party website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to have twitter login page on third party website? and when I enter credentials it should  directly login to twitter.Is there any way?

Currently now am using twitter_oauth which redirects me to twitter login page. But I want the twitter login page on my site.Sorry if it very pathetic question but I want to know this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488155/oauth-twitter-and-facebook-apps-within-iframes. Is this helpfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do that,but recently twitter recently restricted its api to only **HTTPS enabled** websites...see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239)